# Add credit card as a payment method when order is placed through admin

Tags: magento2

I want to add credit card as a payment method when order is placed through admin in magento2. The order should be placed using credit card as a payment method.I have attached screen capture of the same. Can anyone give any ideas.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue, we can do this by enabling `Authorize.net` payment method form `Stores->configuration->Sales->payment method->Authorize.net` and then creating an account on sandbox and configuring it.

Answer (score 1):

In magento this solution focus on payment method Store => Configuration => sales => Payment Methods

You have several option
1. Using paypal
2. other payment gateway services

for no 2 it depends on your country payment service gateway company.